# I can not use keyboard for Debian

Tags: linux, debian, keyboard, embedded

I am using **Debian** desktop for **Lichee Pi** and I am new this platform(linux). I **communicate serial with lichee pi using putty**. I made the lichee pi connection with the keyboard using microusb to usb converter, but my keyboard is not working. How can I solve this? My setup looks like this:

[image]

Comment: There is a micro usb port. i used a micro usb to usb converter and connect a keyboard @jsotola

Comment: now you can see the setup in the picture @jsotola

Comment: What exactly doers Putty have to do with this?

Comment: Since the keyboard and mouse are not working, I am connected to the processor through the "serial port". @ChanganAuto

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was confused thinking that you were expecting local peripherals to work over a remote connection. Now, first thing first, have you tested the keyboard elsewhere?

Comment: yes, keyboard and micro usb to usb device is working on another device @ChanganAuto

Comment: Is it recognized at all? Try running `lsusb` (remotely).

Comment: when i write this,it return "unable to initialize lsusb : -99" @ChanganAuto

Comment: So probably USB support isn't working. Why, I don't know. Maybe this? -> https://github.com/balena-os/balena-raspberrypi/issues/493

Comment: It doesn't recognize the USBs I inserted. But the link you gave is related to ubuntu. This is debian. @ChanganAuto

Comment: It may or may not be applicable, the kernel version likely matters more than anything else. I suggest you search in a forum dedicated to your specific device.

Comment: Thank you ChanganAuto. I'm sure my new vehicle will be Changan Auto! @ChanganAuto

Comment: If you live where they're available go for it! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after use a micro usb to usb converter, it worked. I think female-female usb cable is not supported for this ecosystem